# jQuery UI drag and drop issue with scroll

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a div-pop-up when you click certain text. I want it to be movable so I used the jQuery UI `draggable()` feature and works like a charm.  However, the issue I am having is with a div within this pop up.  I am displaying information from an array that can range from 0 to nearly infinity if needed.  Therefore I am using `overflow:auto` to make it into a scroll box.  Everything appears as it should however, when I click the up and down arrows to scroll up and down within that box it instead begins the draggable feature.  It is rather annoying and understand why the problem is happening.  I am looking for advice to fix it or get around it somehow.

Here is a jsfiddle to display the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/BnTPG/

Comment: Probably not easy to fix, seeing as the scrollbars are a browser feature. It works properly on Firefox when clicking in the up/down arrow and blank scroll space, but glitches when you try to drag the scroll bar. Now try on Chrome for extra fun.

Comment: I designed it on chrome and didn't test in other browsers... My main issue is in chrome.  I realize its not an easy fix and I am also looking for any ideas to do the same thing in a different manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the handle option. Take a look (I modified your fiddle). In my example, I set the title as the handle of the draggable and I used some ids instead of the classes as you did.

http://jsfiddle.net/BnTPG/2/

I think you are having this problem because you are using relative and absolute positioning (it's just a guess, I didn't tested this).

Comment: I did think of making ONLY the title clickable and draggable but I still wanted the whole box to be clickable other than the inner scrolling div but this seems to be the only logical answer at this point and I am going to have to go with it.  Thanks for the suggestion and fix, I will probably end up going with this.

Comment: I think that this approach is the more natural to the users, since they are used to drag dialogs using the title bar, not dialog body. I tried various things to try to solve this, but with no success.

Comment: I appreciate the help and yes, I agree, it is very natural to grab the top of a box to drag.

Answer (score 0):

For my part i really prefer to Drag all my Popup where i want.

If you want  to resolve your problem you must add a DIV wrap the div who scroll, because with Firefox i think the Scrollbar is link to the parent div who is dragable and not the schildren who is only scrollable.

```
                $('body').on("mousedown", ".draggable", function(e) {

                    // Impossible to drag these LIEN, INPUT, TEXTAREA, SELECT
                    var clicked = $(e.target).get(0).tagName;
                    if (clicked == 'A' || clicked == 'INPUT' || clicked == 'TEXTAREA' || clicked == 'SELECT') {
                            return true;
                    }
                    if ($(e.target).parents().hasClass('selectable')) {
                            return true;
                    }

                    // Stop clic action
                    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                    } else {
                            window.event.returnValue = false;
                    }

                    ... etc ...


<div id="debuger" class="draggable" style="overflow: hidden;">
     <div class="selectable">
          <div id="text"> Scrollable text </div>
</div></div>
```