# How to drag and drop when scrolling is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, scroll

I am working in JavaScript and stuck in a problem and need help from experts.
here is my scenario I have a div which has two divs inside it.I want my outer div to be draggable and one of my inner div has a scrolling option in it

```
<div id = "par" class "ui-draggable" style="position: relative; height: 200px; width: 540px;">

    <div width="440" height="182" style="float: left;">
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100px; height: 182px; float: left; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; ">
    </div>

</div>
```

Then I have wrote following code to make my div draggable

```
 $('#par').draggable();
```

It working fine and is draggable.
But I am now stuck in a problem that when I click on scroll bar and then try to drop my div.I does not drop.Any idea what I have done wrong or is there a way to correct it.
I an using chrome browser.it working fine in fire fox but not in chrome
Here is a link to Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xhMgu/

Thanks any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle, or another demo that we can see?

Comment: So are you talking about when you click on the scrollbar and then drag and drop it?

Comment: @Steven. His problem is when he have some component with scrollbars. The scrollbars won't work if the component that has them is inside the draggable one. When you click (in the scrollbar) the component is dragged and the scrollbar don't work as expected. To solve this he needs to use a dragabble handle as I said in my answer. Take a look in his fiddle. Try to use the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the "handle" option of the draggable component. Using it, you will delegate the dragging handle to another tag. If you use your top container as a draggable (the default behaviour) you will have the problem that you said. Take a look at my answer here: [jQuery UI drag and drop issue with scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533864/jquery-ui-drag-and-drop-issue-with-scroll/)